# Created a docker image with Flyway migrations inside

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, flyway

I want to create a docker image, which contains PostgresQL with Flyway migrations already run.

How can I do this?
Actually I need 
1) to run a container with postgres running and run in it flyway transaction
2) copy DB directory to a new image during build

2) is easy, but I failed with 1):
how can create a docker image to start postgres and then run java?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to start a Postgres container and another with Java? This way you can run flyway scripts and then fire up your application.

Comment: I would like to do it at build, not at runtime to decrease downtime

Comment: What have you tired? What are the problems?

Comment: @OleksandrShpota the exntry point of postgres image is running postgres itself. So I can't run java just after postgres starts.
No I found a workaround to run flyway migrations as docker exec after containers starts

Comment: @PavelBernshtam, can you elaborate on what you ended up doing?  I am trying to do the same thing.  I got everything to work with Docker compose but I want to publish the updated database/Docker image for others to use.

Comment: @OldManProgrammer During build time I create a docker image with postgres, java and my application uber jar. Start container using my image. Using 'docker exec' run java with my migrations. Using "docker copy" I copy postgres docker directory to the host machine. Stops this container. Then I create a new image, inherited from postgres image with this, prepared data directory